# DBpedia SPARQL query that has a period in it

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get the abstract of the Manchester United soccer team, problem is the wiki link has periods in it. When I tried this,

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp2: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?abstract
WHERE {
    dbp:Manchester_United_F.C.
    dbp2:abstract ?abstract . 
    FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract), 'en')
}
```

It returned an error because of the period after F.C.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've seen in the SPARQL grammar, you might need to expand the prefix to get `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Manchester_United_F.C.>` as your reference.

Comment: Excellent, it worked just as you mentioned. You don't have any idea on how to get the query to work if the resource has an accent in it do you? For example someone's last name which has an accent.

Comment: @Jako: You can use `\u` and `\U` with hex digits after them; see http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#codepointEscape.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep asking you questions, but I'm trying to get the abstract for Dejan Stanković

I looked up the hex digits for the acute c and found it to be \u0107, but I'm still having problems running a query with \u0107 in place of the ć, it's returning errors.

Comment: @Jako: I don't know in that case; I was just searching the documentation to find the solution to your problem.  Does that link I posted have anything helpful?  There are examples of Unicode characters in there.

Comment: You can URL encode the ć like this:   
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dejan_Stankovi%C4%87>