# D2RQ/Update Server Cannot insert properties

Tags: sparql, insert-update

I have a SPARQL/Update query likes below.

```
INSERT { <http://localhost:8080/resource/User/166> rdf:type seagent:User;
         seagent:User.email 'xyz@gmail.com'.
}
```

After execution of this query user has been inserted but properties of user not. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following the question and answer at [DBpedia SPARQL query that has a period in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207891/dbpedia-sparql-query-that-has-a-period-in-it), your query probably fails (apparently gracefully) on the period (`.`) in the predicate `seagent:User.email`.

You can expand the prefix to the property's full URI `<http://example.org/#User.email>` or define a different prefix `PREFIX seagent-user: <http://example.org/#User.>` and use that: `... seagent-user:email 'xyz@gmail.com'.`

However, you may want to review the URIs for the properties and remove periods to avoid this kind of problems, if this is your own ontology. Or you could use a well known ontology like [FOAF](http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/) that includes properties to link email address to a person or user account.

Comment: thanks for reply, but my proplem not related to your answer. I realized that cause of this proplem is DataTypePropertyDefinition in my mapping file so I removed DataTypePropertyDefinition and problem has been solved. Thanks again.